# Web scrape data from finance website using R (rvest)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from  [ADM finance](https://www.e-adm.com/futr/futr_composite_window.asp). I am using `rvest` library of `R` to pull the data. Below is the code, I am running

```
library(rvest)
url ="https://www.e-adm.com/futr/futr_composite_window.asp"
table1 = html(url) %>% html_nodes(".miniText tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)    .smTextBlk") %>% html_nodes("table") %>%html_table
table2 = html(url) %>% html_nodes(".miniText tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) .smTextBlk") %>% html_nodes("table") %>%html_table
```

and getting following warning message with no data

```
Warning message:
'html' is deprecated.
Use 'read_html' instead.
See help("Deprecated")
```

My objective is to pull all the tables from this website. It would be a great help if anyone can help me with code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
url ="https://www.e-adm.com/futr/futr_composite_window.asp"

tableList <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes(".miniText") %>% 
    html_nodes("td table") %>% 
    html_table()
```

This creates a list of the 9 tables in the linked website.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is working. It would be great if you can explain- why did you use function `html_nodes()` twice?

Comment: Mostly for tidiness, it can be collapsed into `html_nodes(".miniText td table")`